# Yii2 Gridview: how to call model function one time, but use it's results in multiple columns?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

In model I have function:

```
public function getResult($id)
{
    $result = new \stdClass();
    $result->alfa = $id.10;
    $result->beta = $id.20;
    $result->delta = $id.50;
    return $result;
}
```

In grid view I'd like to call this function ONLY ONE time, but display each value in separate column. Now view looks like that:

```
[
    ...
    [
        'value' => function($item){
            $res = $item->result();
            return $res->alfa;
        },
    ],
    [
        'value' => function($item){
            $res = $item->result();
            return $res->beta;
        },
    ],
    [
        'value' => function($item){
            $res = $item->result();
            return $res->delta;
        },
    ],
    ...
]
```

I've read, that there is no way to pass value from one column to another, but it should be some work around, right? So far I've tried to get values before columns and then add it like that: function($item) use ($result) {}, also called function from search model, but I can't (or just don't know how) pass values to them.

In 'real' model I get values with request - there is no way to split it, also, those calculations are quite complex, so I need to get rid of those multiple calls, because as you can imagine loading time is nasty with those extra calls

Thanks for any helpful info or ideas!

Comment: Are the results of `getResult()` depending on the property that this method is called on?

Comment: Yes, they are - these values are calculated for given item specifically, some parameters change within the calculations depending on the item

Comment: It's difficult to give you a specific answer without the code but in general - you can store the results of calculations in some model private property and use them on the next call.

Comment: You could use afterFind function ..  and assigne to fields the proper values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much for suggestions, it really helped! This is what I ended up doing:

**Model**

```
private $_alfa, $_beta, $_delta;

public function getAlfa()
{
    return $this->_alfa;
}

public function getBeta()
{
    return $this->_beta;
}

public function getDelta()
{
    return $this->_delta;
}

public function getResult($id)
{
    $this->_alfa = $id.10;
    $this->_beta = $id.20;
    $this->_delta = $id.50;
}
```

**View**

```
...
[
    'value' => function($item){
        $item->getResult($item->id);
        return $item->getAlfa();
    },
],
[
    'value' => function($item){
        return $item->getBeta();
    },
],
[
    'value' => function($item){
        return $item->getDelta();
    },
],
...
```